# how to read json data from server using angularJs in eclipse?

Tags: angularjs, json, eclipse

```
Hers is my code in html pasted in WebContent folder created using Dynamic Web Project in eclipse:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
      var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
      countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
        $http.get('country_codes.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.countries = data;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
    <h2>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Country</th>

        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries | orderBy: 'code' ">
        <td>{{country.code}}</td>
        <td>{{country.name}}</td>
        <td>{{country.population}}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

The json data is written in "country_codes.json" which is placed at the same location where html file has been placed.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfKwQ.png)

**But I am getting the output as shown in below image.Please let me know why it is not reading data from server**

Answer (score 0):

you missed ng-app directive

```
<body ng-app="countryApp" ng-controller="CountryCtrl">.....</body>
```

Comment: Thanks it works ,But please let me know where should i place files from which I have to read data in eclipse dynamic web project . Another thing I often confused about that I have placed json file at the same location as html file so why it is said that I have reading file from server.

Comment: Pleasse let me know what I asked above?